# Convert a typed racket file to untyped racket?

Tags: racket, typed-racket

Is there any way to manually convert a typed racket file to untyped racket file without using typed\racket\no-check function?

Comment: Any way to *manually* do it? Just remove all the type annotations.

Comment: @AlexisKing That....and all of the typed/racket only forms like `define:` and `for:` and `struct:`.

Comment: Don't remove them, turn them into type comments so they can be used as signatures for HtDP

Comment: how to turn them into type comment? Please give an example , it will be easier to understand for me @AlexKnauth

Comment: [Here's a link to the Reader documentation I found](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html#%28part._default-readtable-dispatch%29)  , not really into typed racket so give it a read and see if it helps you, good luck!

Comment: I think the real question here is, why don't you want to use the `typed\racket\no-check` *language*?

Comment: I just wanted to know how it works for my study purpose. can you kindly tell me what steps it follows(work flow) when convert a typed file? @LeifAndersen